# WebView no android mostra HTML

Tags: java, html, android, android-webview

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação android, que uso um webservice para pegar noticias de um site e jogar pro aplicativo. Essas noticias vem em HTML e eu pego um webview e seto o HTML para ele, e funciona perfeitamente nas API's level >= 19. Estou utilizando o `wbConteudo.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/",noticia.getConteudo(),"text/html; charset=utf-8", "utf-8",null);` para setar dados no webview, pois existem notícias que são fixas e resolvi deixar as fotos na pasta "asset" do android e depois carrega-las junto com o conteudo HTML.

Porém quando uso uma api level < 19, a webview me mostra o código HTML puro para o usuário ao invés do formatado("teste"), gostaria de saber o que está acontecendo, pois preciso que funcione na API level abaixo de 19.

Ex:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fiz um teste aqui, e utilizando o `wbConteudo.loadData(noticia.getConteudo(),"text/html; charset=utf-8", "utf-8");` e ele funcionou o conteudo HTML, porém as fotos internas que estão na pasta "asset" não funcionam pois não estou utilizando o `wbConteudo.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/",noticia.getConteudo(),"text/html; charset=utf-8", "utf-8",null);`

Então gostaria de saber o que está ocorrendo e o por que está ocorrendo e uma possível solução.

Código Tela:

```
public class NoticiaFragment extends Fragment {
private Noticia noticia;
public static Integer aba;

public NoticiaFragment(){

}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    noticia = new Noticia(bundle.getString("titulo"), bundle.getString("conteudo"));
    NoticiaFragment.aba = bundle.getInt("ABA");
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_noticia,null);
    TextView txTitulo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txTitulo);
    WebView wbConteudo = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.wbConteudo);
    txTitulo.setText(noticia.getTitulo());
    wbConteudo.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/",noticia.getConteudo(),"text/html; charset=utf-8", "utf-8",null);//Isso funciona perfeitamente API >= 19
    //wbConteudo.loadData(noticia.getConteudo(),"text/html; charset=utf-8", "utf-8");//Isso funciona em API < 19
    wbConteudo.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    return view;
}

public static int getAba() {
    return aba;
}

public static void setAba(int aba) {
    NoticiaFragment.aba = aba;
}
```

}

Código Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/fragment_noticia"
>

<TextView
    android:text="Titulo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txTitulo"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:textAppearance="@style/tituloNoticia"
    android:gravity="center"/>

<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/wbConteudo" /></LinearLayout>
```

Grade:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "br.com.patrick.fetiep"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

`}`

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'

compile 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'

compile files('libs/activation.jar')
compile files('libs/additionnal.jar')
compile files('libs/mail.jar')
compile files('libs/gson-2.2.4-sources.jar')
compile files('libs/org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client-4.1.2.jar')
compile files('libs/picasso-2.5.2.jar')
```

}

Comment: Cara, vai ser bem difícil alguém vir aqui e te dizer exatamente onde está o seu erro...Só o que posso te dizer é para ter cuidado com a versão que está utilizando para desenvolver. O próprio site oficial do Developer.Android já "Recomenda utilizar a versão da API 19+). O que posso te adiantar é que apenas uma baixa porcentagem de pessoas utilizam versões anteriores a essa. Você pode checar [aqui](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) as versões que estão sendo mais utilizadas no momento. E se tiver dúvidas de quais métodos ainda continuam nessa mudança de versões, pode ver